# post data to view using ajax

Tags: python, ajax, pyramid

I have a template 'mytemplae.pt':

```
function do_option_ajax() {

               var address = document.getElementById('url').value;
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "url_option",
                   data: JSON.stringify({url: $(address)}),
                   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   error: function () {
                       alert('error')
                   },
                   success: function (data) {
                       alert('Success');
                   }
               })
           }


<form method="post" action="index">
  <input type="url " name="url" id='url' size="100">
    <button id="2" formaction="url_option" onclick="do_option_ajax()">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

in .py file:

```
config.add_route('option', '/url_option')
@view_config(route_name='option', renderer='json', request_method='POST')
def option(request):
    url = request.params['url']
    # do something and create json_result
    return json_result
```

with these I want to send back json_result to the view and do something with it, but it returns an empty view with jsob obect printed:
[image]

Comment: You return JSON, and that is what your output displays. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to pass json data to the view, in success callback of ajax post. but it doesn't work

Comment: That still doesn't explain anything. What doesn't work? And what do you mean by "the view" here? I can clearly see JSON in that screenshot. What else were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to render 'mytemplae' again while the json is sent to it as data object of success callback, not as the screenshot above

Comment: OK. Where have you written code to do that?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to write it

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Try rewriting it.  What exactly are you trying to do? What is the result you want returned in the Ajax post? Do you want your rendered mytemplate.pt returned in the json post data?

Comment: I think this question needs some editing; it is unclear what author tries to accomplish and has not written enough background story about the use case.

Comment: I want after returning in 'def option(request)', the callcack function of ajax (success: function (data)), be called, and json_result, returned as data parameter of seccess callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default form action from firing in Javascript. At the moment your `onclick` handler is invoked and a millisecond later the standard HTML form submit kicks in. The standard form submit receives the data from the server and displays it as a new page.

To prevent this you need to do something like

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="url " name="url" id='url' size="100">
    <button id="2">Confirm</button>
</form>


$("#myform").on('submit', function (e) {

    var address = document.getElementById('url').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url_option",
        data: JSON.stringify({url: $(address)}),
        ...
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that I'm listening for the form submit event, not the button click, and also I removed `action` and `method` attributes from the form as they only do harm in this case.